# Connect to SIP server through PROXY Server

Tags: proxy, asterisk, firewall, centos7, squid

[Network Configuration diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CfsV.jpg)

Hi All,
I Need LAN Computers (X lite Client) to be able to connect to VoIP Server (Asterisk).
How can i configure the proxy server for this purpose.my diagram is in above link.can you help to connect X lite client to VoIP server.

Following are the Configuration.

- LAN - X Lite Client

  - need to connct to example.com:5060 to register client
- Proxy Server - Centos 7

  - Squid Proxy
  - etho0 - 192.168.1.250 /connect to ADSL Router ,Masquerade zone disable
  - etho1 - 192.168.1.0/24 connect to LAN , DHCP Server enable
- VoIP Server - Asterisk   11.20.0 1.el7.centos

  - SIP ports 5004 - 5082 UDP
  - RTP Ports 10000 - 20000 UDP

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: my xlite client cant connect to sip server

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SQUID for proxy SIP.

Should be sip proxy, for example you can use kamailio.org

Comment: when i enable etho0 to Masquerade zone LAN X Lite client can connect..
is there any firewall rules to fix this??

Comment: Yes, you can masquarade rule for destination of your sip server only. https://www.howtoforge.com/internet-connection-sharing-masquerading-on-linux

Comment: when i enable Masquerade LAN users can access  web sites freely.if they set browsers "No Proxy" they can connect to internet.and download torrents.
is there any method to enable Masquerade for sip ports ??

Comment: Yes, you can do NAT/Masquarade for any set of traffic. Read iptables manual carefully.

Comment: Thanks
centos7 dosen't work iptables.i cannot find how to do it using firewalld ?